# combine two DOS windows dialog ,who can help me?

Tags: dos

Now ,I want to run mongodb and acitivemq in windows system ,but that will appear to have two
DOS windows dialog. however,I want them to run in a single dos window,at the same time,I do not want to run them as the services of the system. who can 
help me? the following is my bat file:

start apache-activemq-5.6.0\bin\activemq.bat

start mongodb.bat

Comment: Try `call`ing the two things in question, e.g., `call mongodb.bat`. Although personally, if they have debug output, I'd rather see them both, and use two windows.

Comment: thanks,but it can not help

Comment: I am dispointed,any one here do not can answer my question,you are low?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the linux/unix equivalent of background run

```
programe &
```

You could try:

```
START /B programe1
START /B programe2
```